# How do I put a seek bar in an alert dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, alert, seekbar

I want an alert dialog box to pop up after I click a button to have a seek bar so that the person can change the value from 1-48. I've made a custom xml that has a seek bar and two text view and I would like the dialog box to have two buttons, one just cancels the dialog and the other does more work. Here is the code I have so far.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <SeekBar android:max="48" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/seekBar1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_marginTop="74dp"></SeekBar>
    <TextView android:text="Change Hour Range" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="Only most recent positions" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="15dp"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the alert dialog that I have so far

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(ImTracking.this)
                    //is there something like setcontentview for alert dialogs?

                    .setPositiveButton("Cancel", null)
                    .setNegativeButton("OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
 // does some work here
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yep `builder.setView(View v);` here is how you can use it.

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourLayoutId, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourLayoutRoot));
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setView(layout);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
    SeekBar sb = (SeekBar)layout.findViewById(R.id.yourSeekBar);
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){
            //Do something here with new value
        }
    });
```

Edit: Added progressListener to sample code. Do note that you cannot get a reference to your SeekBar until ***after*** you call alertDialog.show(), if the SeekBar is not being shown findViewById() will return null. Also note that you must use `layout.findViewById();` because the SeekBar is a child of the RelativeLayout that 'layout' is a reference to.

Comment: As you can see, I have a seekbar inside of the custom dialog layout. Where do I put the methods for the seekbar (onprogress changed etc..)

Comment: You can set a progressListener like you normally would. See edit.

Answer (score 2):

```
    //This is the code you seek!

 public void ShowDialog(){
   final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 final SeekBar seek = new SeekBar(this);
   seek.setMax(255);
  seek.setKeyProgressIncrement(1);

 popDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
popDialog.setTitle("Please Select Into Your Desired Brightness ");
popDialog.setView(seek);


 seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {



 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){


  txtView.setText("Value of : " + progress);
  }
```

Or you can look on this [tutorial](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/09/how-to-put-seek-bar-in-alert-dialog.html)